# How to print an ArrayList? - java

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

Question will be below.

```
public class University {
ArrayList<Student> students;

public University() {
    students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}

public void addStudent(Student students) {
    this.students.add(students);
}}
```

---

```
public class Student {
String name;
String studentID;
static int studentNumber = 0;

Student(String name, String sID){
    this.name = name;
    this.studentID = sID;
    studentNumber++;
}}
```

---

```
public class TestUniversity {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    University universityRegister = new University(); 
    Student studentRegister = new Student("Rachel Green", "a1234");
    universityRegister.addStudent(studentRegister);
    
    studentRegister = new Student("Monica Geller", "a12345");
    universityRegister.addStudent(studentRegister);
    
    studentRegister = new Student("Ross Geller", "a1111");
    universityRegister.addStudent(studentRegister);
    
    System.out.println("Number of student in University: " + Student.studentNumber);        
}}
```

A. I created 3 classes, 1.Student, 2.University, 3.UniversityTester, in 3 different files.

B. I created 3 objects of type Studnet, and stored them in the University class as an ArrayList.

I would like to know how I can print the ArrayList of the students including all information from the UniversityTester class? In the future, I will create another object called Stuff and I will store it in the University class as an ArrayList stuffList. Therefore, I don't want to print the students list from class Student.

Comment: It can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: You could also add a print method to class Student, printing the data of one student in your desired format. Then loop over universityRegister.students and call the former method for each retrieved student.

Answer (score 0):

Override toString() method in Student class as follows:

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Student {
  String name;
  String studentID;
  static int studentNumber = 0;

  Student(String name, String sID) {
    this.name = name;
    this.studentID = sID;
    studentNumber++;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return new StringJoiner(", ", Student.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
        .add("name='" + name + "'")
        .add("studentID='" + studentID + "'")
        .toString();
  }
}
```

Now you can print the array list as follows in TestUniversity:

```
System.out.println("Student Details: " + universityRegister.students);
```

Comment: Great! If it resolves the issue then accept the answer and give it an upvote. Keep coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your student class:

```java
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("Student: %s , StudentID: %s", name, studentID);
  }
```

And then you can print the entire array like this:

```java
System.out.println("Students: " universityRegister.students);

//Or like this:

for(Student st: universityRegister.students){
 System.out.println(st);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I love it! first time for me to see the method String.format();

Comment: Glad for it (: If it resolved your issue, remember to accept this answer on the top left side of it, and give it a positive rating please. Thank you :3